# Running node in background from expect script

Tags: node.js, expect

I am trying to run several node services from the expect script, so to run them one by one, I need to run them in background. Running it in from console works fine (processes are up and started in background), like:

```
>node /path/to/service1/myService1.js &> /var/log/myService1.log &
>node /path/to/service2/myService2.js &> /var/log/myService2.log &
```

but running my expect script, which is like:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set customer_root_dir "/path"
set customer_app_dir "/to"
set services {"service1" "service2"}
set service_names {"myService1" "myService2"}


# Set the maximum match length
match_max [ expr 32 * 1024 ]

foreach service $services service_name $service_names {
    spawn node $customer_root_dir/$customer_app_dir/$service/$service_name.js &> /var/log/$service_name.log &
    sleep 2
}

puts "All services are running!"
```

I see that they are started not in background.. and all what comes after service file (eg `service1.js`), I mean  `&> /var/log/myService1.log &`, is ignored! If I type something like `spawn node $customer_root_dir/$customer_app_dir/$service/$service_name.js abracadabra` expect script will run it as just `spawn node $customer_root_dir/$customer_app_dir/$service/$service_name.js`

**What I tried?**

- I tried to replace `spawn` with `exec`
- I tried `send "pawn node $customer_root_dir/$customer_app_dir/$service/$service_name.js &> /var/log/$service_name.log &\r"` but still have no luck.
- I also tried `nohup` but the processes did not start and `/var/log` doesn't contain my log files.

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: Have you tried [PM2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) to run these scripts? It should be easier and faster to manage them.

Comment: thanks for the comment! nope didn't try, the thing is that I need to use expect script, because it's a requirement and the services are on the remote server (that is why expect is using) and all rights on that server are like "run that nodes" and I don't think that I can install something there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
set js  $customer_root_dir/$customer_app_dir/$service/$service_name.js
set log /var/log/$service_name.log

exec nohup node $js < /dev/null >& $log &
```

Note that the Tcl redirection to write stdout and stderr to a file is `>&` (see [exec](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/exec.htm) man page). Also redirecting all stdio channels to disconnect from the terminal.

`spawn` is not the right command: you don't need to interact with the process, so just `exec` it and forget about it.

Comment: The variables aren't strictly necessary, but they make things easier to read.

Comment: agreed. I've had the log variable, but it was like in my first code snippet &> /var/log/myService1.log & , but it didnt work.. wondering why running with &> from console redirects stdout/err to a file? If it should be >& ? And doesn't work from the expect script..

Comment: bash uses either `&>` or `>&` (first preferred) but Tcl uses `>&` only.

Comment: ah, got it! :) sorry, hard day